# Default value of column (when value is set to NULL) equal to other column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, hsqldb

Part of my SQL definition (for [hsqldb](/questions/tagged/hsqldb)):

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
  id  BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  group_id  BIGINT NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT pk_activities PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The scenario during and `insert` is:

- `id` is auto generated / auto-incremented,
- `group_id` when specified (non-null) is set to the given value,
- `group_id` when not specified is set to the value of `id` just generated

I target [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) and [hsqldb](/questions/tagged/hsqldb) (for tests).

**Can this be done?**

Comment: **Err**.. didn't saw the it is in [tag:HSQLDB]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set default value to be that of another column.

However, you can create a [TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) that would accomplish this task.

This is an example for PostgreSQL. It automatically replaces `column` with `anothercolumn` if it is `NULL` before `INSERT` or `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytable_fn()
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.column ISNULL THEN
        NEW.column := NEW.anothercolumn;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytable_fn();
```

Comment: Are triggers universal / standardized? Can you provide a related example?

Comment: @JohanesMatian: As far as I know, most modern databases (PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL) do implement triggers, but language is not necessarily compatible. I don't know much about hsqldb, though. I have updated my answer to give an example for Postgres.

Comment: @JohanesMatian: `hsqldb` [supports triggers](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/triggers-chapt.html#trc_before_triggers) as well. Language is slightly different, but I think you should be able to write similar trigger for `hsqldb`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a trigger or if you dont want to use triggers is to handle the NULL when selecting rows like this:

```
SELECT id, isnull(group_id, id) group_id FROM activities;
```

Comment: `ISNULL()` is not standard SQL function. For example, PostgreSQL does not support it. Also, this does not change value for the field in question

Comment: HSQLDB supports all variants of IFNULL, ISNULL, NULLIF, COALESCE etc. used in different database engines. See the Guide.